# Hashmap returning only one value out of all WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap

I am trying to get all the results from amazon website of search results toy car  in a hashmap but it is storing only the first value.I am also returning the results of this hashmap in the main method
Please find a snippet of my code below
public HashMap<Integer, String> amazonresults(WebDriver driver) {

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> adf = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    driver.get("http://amazon.in");

    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));
    a.moveToElement(searchbox).click().sendKeys("toy car").build().perform();
    a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
            List<WebElement> product = driver
            .findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class ='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']"));

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {

        adf.put(i, (product.get(i).getText()));
    }
    return adf;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SagarikaRoyChoudhury\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Scope sc = new Scope();
    System.out.println(sc.amazonresults(driver));
```

}

Comment: Amazon provides an [API that allows retrieval of product information](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Overview.html).

Comment: Does 'List<WebElement> product' contain multiple elements or only one? put SOP there.

Comment: I've tested your code with higher implicit wait (30 seconds) and it's working fine.